# duplicate elements of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to duplicate elements of an array in JavaScript and add them to the same array.

```
    function duplicate(arr) {
    // Write Logic here
    var position,lengtharr = arr.length;
    for(var i=0;i<lengtharr;++i){
        arr[position] = arr[i];
        position++;
    }
    
    return arr;
}

var arr=[1,2];

console.log(duplicate(arr));
```

Please explain why the above code is not working. I'm getting "Incorrect Output" as error.

Also, I've come up with another way as shown below. But I'd like to know what's wrong with this approach.

```
function duplicate(arr) {
    // Write Logic here
    var lengtharr = arr.length;
    for(var i=0;i<lengtharr;++i){
        arr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    
    return arr;
}

var arr=[1,2];

console.log(duplicate(arr));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add elements to the end of the array. That way you don't need that extra `position` variable.

```js
function duplicate(arr) {
  const len = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    arr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}

let arr= [1, 2];

console.log(duplicate(arr));
```

Comment: `arr.push(...arr)` should do the trick too ;)

Comment: Sure, but I was keeping with the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Try this **:**

```js
function clone(arr) {
  arr.push(...arr);
  return arr;
}

var arr=[1,2];

console.log(clone(arr));
```